# TFS Build Server 2013 and XUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, build, xunit

I'm having trouble setting up TFS Build server on a locally hosted build machine.

I have the usual test structure i.e.

```
--\HellowWorld\HelloWorld.sln
--\HellowWorld\HelloWorld.csproj
--\HelloWorld.Tests\HellowWorld.Tests.csproj
```

I am using visualstudio online and a local buildserver for the builds and deploys.

I have no problem getting a c# .net application to download the source, build and deploy.

I have created a folder for XUNIT with the necessary dlls and checked into TFS

In the  dialogue for the Build Server for 'Version control path to custom assemblies' as follows

> > $/IT Development/Bin/XUnit

In this folder are the following dlls

```
xunit.abstractions.dll
xunit.runner.utility.dll
xunit.runner.visualstudio.settings.dll
xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll
```

The following blog post suggests this should be enough

```
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02bce20c-1e5b-47cc-8f64-0ff8aa5a19cf/tfs-2012-build-to-run-xunittest?forum=tfsbuild
```

I get the following in the Build output

> >
>    $/IT Development/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln compiled
>   $/IT Development/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln - 0 error(s), 6 warning(s), View Log File
>    No Test Results
>    No Code Coverage Results
>   Impacted Tests
>   No tests were impacted

Comment: in your build definition have you specified the test runner?

Comment: Have you added the DLLs to the custom binaries folder of your controller?

Comment: yes and yes to both questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing Visual Studio Professional on the build server. This gives access to the VisualStudio Test Runner on the build machine. Brute force but it was the easiest option.

Comment: This is the correct solution. It is not bruit force. Your build server needs to mirror dev.

Comment: I don't think so MrHinsh. I think I should have installed a test agent

Comment: Test agests are not for running unit tests as a developer activity but running automation as a Tester activity. I get your point but build servers (compilation) get VS and Test servers get an agent.

Comment: No, build servers do not get VS, they get the Team Foundation Build Service.